# MissingAttributeError when trying to order index based on average rating

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to order an index based on the average value of ratings. Rating is an integer attribute on the review model.
Here are my relevant models:

**provider.rb**

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id', autosave: true
  has_many :reviews, :through => :user, dependent: :destroy

  def reviews
    Review.where("provider_id = ?", id)
  end
end
```

**review.rb**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :provider, foreign_key: 'provider_id'
end
```

I get the error when trying to access provider attributes in my view, which looks like this:

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @providers.each do |provider| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to provider.name, provider_path(provider.id) %></td>
    <td><%= provider.industry %></td>
    <td><%= provider.tag %></td>
    <td><%= provider.description %></td>
    <td><%= provider.reviews.average(:rating) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The code that is causing this issue (I think) is in my products controller:

**providers_controller.rb**

```
class ProvidersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_provider, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @providers = Provider.select("avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating").joins(:reviews).order("avg_rating DESC")
    @reviews = Review.find_by(params[:provider_id])
  end
```

I am unable to access any of the attributes listed in my view. I am unsure as to whether the problem lies in my view code or my controller code. Thank you for the help.

**Error**

```
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:93:in `block in _read_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:31:in `block in fetch_value'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute.rb:150:in `value'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:31:in `fetch_value'
```

**Error edit**

Showing /home/Danae/RubymineProjects/canvas/app/views/providers/index.html.erb where line #20 raised:

missing attribute: name

**SOLUTION**
Rookie mistake by me. Had a column name that interfered with avg_rating. cschroed's answer is perfect.

Comment: Can you post the entire error and not just "MissingAttributeError?"

Comment: Would that be the full trace?

Comment: Typically yeah. Depending on how long it is you might want to shorten it to just the lowest level lines that tell you where the error is, line number and such.

Comment: Edited question with trace.

Comment: `app/views/providers/index.html.erb:20:in `block in _app_views_providers_index_html_erb___4343438652084474623_27379300'... What is the code around that line?

Comment: That would be <td><%= link_to provider.name, provider_path(provider.id) %></td>, if I remove it, it flags the next line.

Comment: I feel like there's something missing from the error message. Are you getting this error on a view? Typically somewhere near the top of the page there's a line or two indicating where the error is occurring. Can you post that if it's there?

Comment: Edited with info. I believe it is related to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `select("avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating")` no other Provider columns are being selected.  If you want to select the other columns you can use `select("providers.*, avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating")` and then because `avg` is an aggregate function you'll have to also use `group("providers.id")`.  Try:

```
@providers = Provider.select("providers.*, avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating").joins(:reviews).group("providers.id").order("avg_rating DESC")
```

The alias `avg_rating` should be a unique name that does not match any of the column names on your tables.

Comment: This did not throw an error, but presented the results in the same order as Provider.all. Any ideas? Thanks so much for the time.

Comment: (1) Do you have a `default_scope` on your Provider?  (2) In the Rails console, what does `Provider.select("providers.*, avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating").joins(:reviews).group("providers.id").order("avg_rating DESC").to_sql` show? (3) What does `Provider.select("providers.*, avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating").joins(:reviews).group("providers.id").order("avg_rating DESC").map{ |p| p.avg_rating.to_f }` show?

Comment: 1) No default scope. Is this necessary? 2) "SELECT providers.*, avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating FROM \"providers\" INNER JOIN \"users\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"providers\".\"user_id\" INNER JOIN \"reviews\" ON \"reviews\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" GROUP BY providers.id  ORDER BY avg_rating DESC" 3)

Comment: 3) Provider Load (0.6ms)  SELECT providers.*, avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating FROM "providers" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "providers"."user_id" INNER JOIN "reviews" ON "reviews"."user_id" = "users"."id" GROUP BY providers.id  ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
 => [4.333333333333333, 4.0, 5.0]

Comment: Sometimes the default scope sneaks in `ORDER` statements that you didn't intend but that isn't the case here.  Hm, I'm not immediately sure why that didn't order correctly.  Which database are you using?

Comment: SQlite3! Its definitely befuddling me at the moment as well!

Comment: Do you have a column named `avg_rating` on one of your tables that is interfering with the alias for your `avg` computation?  If so, you'd need to use a different alias like `Provider.select("providers.*, avg(reviews.rating) as avg_rating2").joins(:reviews).group("providers.id").order("avg_rating2 DESC")`.